# Can I improve my PDO method (just started)

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I just switched to PDO from mySQLi (from mySQL) and it's so far good and easy, especially regarding prepared statements

This is what I have for a select with prepared statement

Main DB file (included in all pages):

```
class DBi {
    public static $conn;
    // this I need to make the connection "global"
}

try {

    DBi::$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $dbuname, $dbpass);
    DBi::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    DBi::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}

catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo '<p class="error">Database error!</p>';

}
```

And in my page:

```
try {

    $sql = 'SELECT pagetitle, pagecontent FROM mypages WHERE pageid = ? LIMIT 1';

    $STH = DBi::$conn->prepare($sql);

    $STH->execute(array($thispageid));  // $thispageid is from a GET var

}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '<p class="error">Database query error!</p>';
}

    if ($STH) {  // does this really need an if clause for it self?

        $row = $STH->fetch();

        if (!empty($row)) {  // was there found a row with content?

            echo '<h1>'.$row['pagetitle'].'</h1>
            <p>'.$row['pagecontent'].'</p>';

        }

    }
```

It all works. But am I doing it right? Or can I make it more simple some places?

Is using if (!empty($row)) {} an ok solution to check if there was a result row with content? Can't find other decent way to check for numrows on a prepared narrowed select

Comment: try http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: No. "PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement"

Comment: Sure? _If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications._

Comment: I want to make sure that it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '<p class="error">Database query error!</p>';
}
```

I would use the opportunity to log *which* database query error occurred.

See example here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php

Also if you catch an error, you should probably `return` from the function or the script.

```
if ($STH) {  // does this really need an if clause for it self?
```

If `$STH` isn't valid, then it should have generated an exception and been caught previously. And if you had returned from the function in that catch block, then you wouldn't get to this point in the code, so there's no need to test `$STH` for being non-null again. Just start fetching from it.

```
    $row = $STH->fetch();

    if (!empty($row)) {  // was there found a row with content?
```

I would write it this way:

```
$found_one = false;
while ($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    $found_one = true;
    . . . do other stuff with data . . .
}
if (!$found_one) { 
    echo "Sorry! Nothing found. Here's some default info:";
    . . . output default info here . . .
}
```

No need to test if it's empty, because if it were, the loop would exit.

Comment: But I need to revert to some default variables if database fails or returns nothing.. is it just a matter of setting them before the database select, and then changing/resetting them inside the db-select?

Comment: Right now I'm using if ($row !== false) { }

Comment: But you're right.. using just that while thing works sufficiently. I just like to check num_rows and serve something to the user if no rows was found. Can't seem to find a num_rows solution for prepared PDO select

Comment: See my edit above for an example of showing "default" data in case the query returns 0 rows.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't seem so "elegant" if it requires extra code like that, but such is the nature of handling special cases in our applications.

Comment: But the simple function of counting rows from a select query is greatly missing in PDO. Hope it will come soon. I'm used to count rows every time I pull something of the database (mysql/mysqli), and serve different content based on result. And sometimes I even need the exact returned number to calculate. So I go back to good old $count++ ?

Comment: The PDO_MySQL driver does attempt to support rowCount() for SELECT queries as well as other DML, but there could be cases where it doesn't work, like if you use emulated prepare. I haven't tested thoroughly, and the test suite for rowCount() is pretty weak.